# DFA graph in matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, graph-algorithm, dfa

i am trying to design a DFA, with n states and two chars in the sigma,
but i want also to draw the DFA in matlab, and to call functions on the DFA graph,
so what is the best way to represent it ?

Comment: are you aware of stateflow which visually models and simulates complex reactive systems based on finite state machine theory?

Comment: yes, but i need to make it in matrix ..